# How to distinguish gmock expectations created on the same line

Tags: c++, googlemock

I have some test code which sets up expectations like this:

```
InSequence seq;
for (auto const& p : scenario) {
  ON_CALL(mock_object, query(p.input))
    .WillByDefault(Return(p.result));
}
```

Unfortunately, this makes it difficult to identify failed expectations, because they are all reported on the same line.

Is there a way to attach some description to the expectation, that appears in the output in case of failure?

Comment: What kind of description? Can you add the error text? Isn't it going to print the file and the line where it failed?

Comment: Each test should be unique. If you really need make such thing when each object set same expectation then the best thing will be create proper fixture.

Comment: @MichałKalinowski each test should *not* be unique, that's why we have parametrized tests. The original code is from a parametrized test. The tested code can make any number of calls to `query`, therefore the test has to be able to set up any number of expectations.

Comment: @BЈовић It is going to print the file and line, but those are the same for every expectation.

Comment: In your example you are only setting the default actions on the `mock_object`. For sure this is not the reason your test is failing. please post the rest of your code (but keep it minimal) as well as the console output.

Comment: @Ptaq666 My test is not failing because I already figured out which expectation was failing. `WillByDefault` is not the problem. The effect is the same with `EXPECT_CALL` and `WillOnce`. What I want is an easier way to figure out which expectation it is when one fails next time I expand the test.

Comment: It's not clear which line it's being reported on or which line you'd like it to be reported on. Is is being reported on the line of the function-call but you'd like it to mention the expectation, or vice-versa?

Comment: you could call another function, and there keep track what fails

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question now. Unfortunately, it seems googletest does not provide the possibility to override the default `EXPECT_CALL` failure message (someone please correct me if it actually is possible). You will get good descriptive error message if your test invokes the `mock_object::query` with wrong arguments, but not if it doesn't invoke the method at all. As a walk-around you can try the following hack:

```
class SomeMock {
public:
    MOCK_METHOD1(doSth, bool(const int& num));
};

TEST(xxx, yyy) {
    SomeMock mock_object;
    for (auto const& p : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}) {
        EXPECT_CALL(mock_object, doSth(p)).WillOnce(Invoke(
            [](const int& i) {
                std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl; return true;
            }));
    }
    for (auto const& p : {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}) {
        mock_object.doSth(p);
    }
}
```

to know which `EXPECT_CALL` were already satisfied. Or you can use `--gmock_verbose=info` option for a similar effect.